# Why generic type parent type is not understood by the compiler in parent constructor

Tags: kotlin, generics

Following code snippet doesn't compile (Kotlin 1.7.0) because in `PFrag` when calling it's parent (`Frag`) constructor, `V` is not recognized as a subtype of `ViewModel<PRepo>`.
However I think it should because `V` type is `PViewModel<M, R>` with `PViewModel` being a child of `ViewModel` and `R` being a child of `PRepo`.
Is it possible to slighlty modify this code to make it compile (maybe using `out` keyword) ?
Or is it impossible due to some issues I have not yet seen ?

```
interface Model

abstract class Repo

abstract class ViewModel<R: Repo>

abstract class Frag<R: Repo, V: ViewModel<R>>

interface PModel: Model

abstract class PRepo: Repo()

abstract class PViewModel<M: PModel, R: PRepo>: ViewModel<R>()

abstract class PFrag<M: PModel, R: PRepo, V: PViewModel<M, R>>: Frag<PRepo, V>()
```

Comment: Did you mean `abstract class PFrag<M: PModel, R: PRepo, V: PViewModel<M, R>>: Frag<R, V>()`?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much it, this was the issue !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's break this down:

- For `Frag<PRepo, V>` to work, it must be the case that `V : ViewModel<PRepo>`, according to the constraints in `Frag`.
- We know that `V: PViewModel<M, R>`, and also `PViewModel<M, R>: ViewModel<R>` from their respective declarations
- Therefore, `V: ViewModel<R>`
- Even though `R: PRepo`, `V: ViewModel<R>` does not imply `V: ViewModel<PRepo>`. For this to be true, `R` needs to be marked as `out`:

  ```
  abstract class ViewModel<out R: Repo>
  ```

  This prevents you from writing any method/property in `ViewModel` where `R` is in an input position. You can also do:

  ```
  abstract class Frag<R: Repo, V: ViewModel<out R>>
  ```

  which prevents you from using any members from `V` where `R` is in an input position.
- Alternatively, change the base class of `PFrag` to `Frag<R, V>` so that `V : ViewModel<R>` is required, rather than `V : ViewModel<PRepo>`:

  ```
  abstract class PFrag<M: PModel, R: PRepo, V: PViewModel<M, R>>: Frag<R, V>()
  ```

Which of those ways is the most suitable depends on your situation. I cannot tell without more information about what these types represent, though I think changing the base class is most likely what you intended.